# Yii2. Rbac. Связь ролей и разрешений.

Tags: yii2, rules

Прочитал документацию по RBAC. 
Выяснил, что Сперва создается роль, потом для него создаются разрешения. 
И если необходимо, то для данного разрешения создается правило.

Установил dektrium/yii2-rbac. 
Создал Роль. 
Создал Разрешение.

Однако, не могу связать их. Нет этой возможности. 
Я что-то неправильно понял или это плагин кривой?

[image: редактирование роли]

Comment: Судя по вашему описанию и скрину могу предположить что правила создаются тоже через CRUD, а вы создали только роль и разрешение.

Comment: Мне  не нужно правило. Мне нужно привязать разрешения к роли

Comment: Если нужно привязать разрешение к роли, то нужно выбирать не в поле Rule, а в поле Children нужное разрешение